# Instruments does not show any leaks but allocations keep increasing

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

Here is a piece of code to highlight a portion of screen, I would like to know if there is any leaks in this code:

```
- (UIImage*)createImageSection:(UIImage*)image section:(CGRect)section
{
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
float originalWidth = image.size.width * [screen scale]  ;
float originalHeight = image.size.height * [screen scale];
int w = originalWidth * section.size.width ;
int h = originalHeight * section.size.height ;


CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, w , h , 8, w * 8, CGImageGetColorSpace([image CGImage]), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextClearRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth * section.size.width * [screen scale], originalHeight * section.size.height * [screen scale])); // w + h before
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, (float)-originalWidth * section.origin.x , (float)-originalHeight * section.origin.y );
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth , originalHeight ), [image CGImage]);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
//UIImage* resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale: [screen scale]];
UIImage* resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[screen scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp] ;
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
return resultImage ;
```

}

Thanks
DKV

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Autorelease resultImage

```
UIImage* resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[screen scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]
```

to

```
UIImage* resultImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[screen scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp] autorelease];
```

Comment: -1: The method definition has 'create' in it. To follow Apple's guidelines every time you call a method with create, new or alloc in it, you're responsible to release the object, no autoreleased object will be returned.

Comment: @lef2, my bad I didn't even look at the method def. Thanks for letting me know. So, I d take it back. There are no leaks in the code.